# concrete floor grinder to smooth tile floor in kitchen?

Tags: flooring, tile, vinyl-flooring

The floor is solid. The tiles are nearly 1/2" thick. But whether intentional or not, the were laid not so flat. I am redoing the kitchen and want to cut corners in terms of cost (it's already tens of thousands, yes?) - so to avoid demolition of this solid floor, I'd like to smooth it out before laying down a new vinyl floor. I know that I could skim coat, but that would cause the height to be off even more in an adjacent marble floor. I also know that I could tear out the tile, but I thought that possibly smoothing it down with a concrete grinder would be a good option. Thoughts?

Comment: Kitchen floor probably not the best place to cut corners, it usually gets quite a bit of abuse.  Would like to know why the tiles are not flat on a solid floor.  Do not know how the tiles would last(long term) if the tops were ground off.  Adding type of tile and type of vinyl flooring to the question might help.  Changing from tile to vinyl seems like a downgrade(depends on type of vinyl)

Comment: Having just played with grinding thinset, a couple of notes. 1 — this is hard to do. 2 — make serious plans for dust control.

Comment: I just spent the better part of a month fckning around with a concrete floor. Until the boss dropped ~$1k on a triple head floor grinder and we were done in a day. They made us have to also rent a giant vacuum (because EPA BS) and we didn't even use it because then we'd have to clean it instead of our own shop vac that we dgaf about. Do it wet and there will be no dust whatsoever.

Comment: Tear out the tile, then smooth it down with a concrete grinder. Grinding the tile? Yeah, no. They'll just break and you'll be chipping it all up and then having to grind the thinset anyway. *The floor is solid* ... concrete? Or it's *sound*? Sound don't count. If it's concrete; get it back to concrete.

Comment: "sound". Probably plywood under tile.